# Get tab selected Id in jQuery UI 1.9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

How can I get the tab selected Id in jQuery UI 1.9?

I use this method in jQuery UI 1.8 :

```
var key = $('#chart-report-tabs .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').prop('id');
```

but it does not work in the 1.9 version.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#chart-report-tabs .ui-tabs-panel[aria-hidden="false"]').prop('id');
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, it works in 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$("#<id of tabs>").tabs("option","active")
```

Returns zero-based index of active tab

Comment: That gives you the desired index, but then how do you get the id of the tab?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $tabs = $('#chart-report-tabs');
var index = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
var key = $tabs.tabs("option", "panel").find('.ui-tabs-panel').eq(index).prop('id');
```

Source: [jQuery UI Tabs selected index](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3a-twb186m9jsJ%3astackoverflow.com/questions/5016541/jquery-ui-tabs-selected-index%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=by)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `activate` or `beforeActivate` events with `ui.newPanel`:

```
$('#chart-report-tabs').tabs({
  activate: function(e, ui) {
    var key = $(ui.newPanel).prop('id');
  }
});
```

#### [Check the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#divName .ui-tabs-panel[aria-hidden="false"]').prop('id');
```